# How can i remove lines from a file when a string appears on multiple lines?

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, sed

I have a file that has 2 columns like the following:

```
apple pear
banana pizza
spoon fork
pizza plate
sausage egg
```

If a word appears on multiple lines i want to delete all lines that the repeating word appears, as you can see 'pizza' appears twice so 2 lines should be deleted, the following is the required output:

```
apple pear
spoon fork
sausage egg
```

I am aware of using :

```
awk '!seen[$1]++'
```

However this only removes the lines when the string appears in one column, i require a command that will check both columns.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: What do you want with one word appearing twice like `giros giros` ?

Comment: @JonnyP : `$i` would refer to column i, so just run a loop for i over all the columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could solve the problem in multiple steps by using `grep` and `uniq -d`.

First, generate a list of all words using something like `grep -Eo '[^ ]+'`. Then filter that list so that only duplicated words remain. Filtering can be done using `… | sort | uniq -d`. Finally, print all lines that do not contain any word from the list previously generated using `grep -Fwvf listFile inputFile`.

In `bash` all these steps can run in one single command. Here we will use the variable `$in` to make it easily adaptable.

```
in="path/to/your/input/file"
grep -Fwvf <(grep -Eo '[^ ]+' "$in" | sort | uniq -d) "$in"
```

Comment: Alternatively, uses `xargs` to split words into a newline delimited list `grep -vwf <(xargs -n1 -a "$in" | sort | uniq -d) "$in"`

Answer (score 2):

Using awk, you can keep track of many things. Not only if you have seen a word, but also which line the word has been seen on. We keep track of a couple of arrays.

- `record`: keeps track of every line we parsed
- `seen`: keeps track of the various words as well as the first record number it has been seen on

This gives us:

```
awk '{ record[NR]=$0 }
     { for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) {
         if ($i in seen) { delete record[NR]; delete record[seen[$i]] }
         else { seen[$i]=NR }
       }
     }
     END { for(i=1;i<=NR;++i) if (i in record) print record[i] }' file
```

How does this work?

- **`record[NR]=$0`**: store the record `$0` in an array `record` indexed by the record number `NR`
- for each field/word of the record check if the word has been seen before. If it has been seen, delete the original record from the array `record` as well as the current record. If it has not been seen, store the word and the current record number in the array `seen`.
- When the full file has been processed, check all possible record numbers we have seen, if it is still an index of the array `record`, print that record.

Comment: When i use this command on the above example file it does't give any response

Comment: @JonnyP see the edited version with Ed Morton's corrections applied.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR {
        for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) {
            if ( firstNr[$i] ) {
                multi[NR]
                multi[firstNr[$i]]
            }
            else {
                firstNr[$i] = NR
            }
        }
        next
    }
    !(FNR in multi)
' file file
apple pear
spoon fork
sausage egg
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR {
        for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) {
            cnt[$i]++
        }
        next
    }
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) {
            if ( cnt[$i] > 1 ) {
                next
            }
        }
        print
    }
' file file
apple pear
spoon fork
sausage egg
```

Comment: I would never have thought about making two passes over the file. Single process and two reads is likely multiple times faster that multiple processes and pipes.

Comment: Yeah or you can do it with one read and store all the lines in an array to process in the END section but that takes up a lot of memory if the file's huge. It just won't work if the input can't be opened twice, e.g. if it's coming from a pipe, and then you'd have to use an array instead of a 2nd pass of the input (e.g. see how [@kvantour did it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56926277/1745001))

Answer (score 0):

This works with your sample:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
filename='x.txt'
for dupe in $(xargs -n1 -a "${filename}" | sort | uniq -d); do
  sed -i.bak -e "/\\<${dupe}\\>/d" "${filename}"
done
```

It builds a list of words that appears more than once in the file:

- `xargs -n1 -a "${filename}"` Outputs the list of all words
  contained in the file (one word per line)
- `| sort` Sorts the list
- `| uniq -d` Outputs only words that appears more than once into consecutive lines

Then uses `sed` to select and delete all lines containing the duped word.

Comment: Or `grep -vwf <(tr ' ' '\n' <"${filename}" | sort | uniq -d) "${filename}"`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU grep,sort,uniq,sed):

```
sed 's/ /\n/g' file | sort |uniq -d | grep -vFf - file
```

Or a toy GNU sed solution:

```
cat <<\! | sed -Ef - file
H         # copy file into hold space
$!d       # delete each line of the original file
g         # at EOF replace pattern space with entire file
y/ /\n/;  # put each word on a separate line
# make a list of duplicate words, space separated
:a;s/^(.*\n)(\S+)(\n.*\b\2\b)/\2 \1\3/;ta
s/\n.*//  # remove adulterated file leaving list of duplicates
G         # append original file to list
# remove lines with duplicate words
:b;s/^((\S+) .*)\n[^\n]*\2[^\n]*/\1/;tb
s/^\S+ //;tb # reduce duplicate word list
s/..//    # remove newline artefacts
!
```